# Is this Python multithreading code with shared tuple thread-safe

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, tuples

Hello Python and multithreading enthusiasts,

I am working on a challenging scenario where I have a shared ***tuple with all immutable elements***, that is frequently iterated by multiple reading threads. Occasionally, this tuple is replaced by a single thread. I don't need guaranteed immediate replacement in the reading threads.

Here is the code that seems to be working without any problems according to our requirements:

```
import threading
import time

# Shared tuple
my_tuple = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

# Function for thread to iterate over the tuple
def iterate_tuple():
    for element in my_tuple:
        print(f"Thread {threading.current_thread().name} - Element: {element}")
        time.sleep(5)

# Function for another thread to replace the tuple
def replace_tuple():
    global my_tuple

    print("Tuple updated")
    my_tuple = (6, 7, 8, 9, 10)

# Create and start the first iterating thread
iterating_thread = threading.Thread(target=iterate_tuple)
iterating_thread.start()

# Sleep to allow the iterating thread to start
threading.Event().wait(1)

# Replace the original tuple with a new one from another thread
replace_thread = threading.Thread(target=replace_tuple)
replace_thread.start()

# Sleep to allow the iterating thread to start
threading.Event().wait(1)

# Create and start the second iterating thread
iterating_thread2 = threading.Thread(target=iterate_tuple)
iterating_thread2.start()

# Wait for threads to finish
iterating_thread.join()
replace_thread.join()
iterating_thread2.join()
```

My questions are:

1. Is this code thread-safe for my use case?
2. How does the for loop still refer to the old tuple without corrupting the data after replacing the tuple?

I appreciate any insights or suggestions you may have! Thank you!

Comment: `for`-loop gets reference to place in memory and it doesn't need variable `my_tuple` any more. And when you assign new value to variable `my_tuple` then variable gets reference to different place in memory - so it doesn't change memory which `for`-loop access.

Comment: Is there any chance that the old reference pointer location will get wiped by garbage cleaner before the end of that for-loop?

Comment: no, there is no option to clean it.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, your code is thread safe as your are using immutable objects (tuples). When you replace my_tuple with replace_tuple. You are not modifying the tuple but redirecting my_tuple to a new tuple.

When a for loop starts going through a tuple, it sticks to that version, even if another thread has changed it. It's like a photocopy, even if the original one was changed, your photocopy stays the same.

Comment: Is there any chance that the old reference pointer location will get wiped by garbage cleaner before the end of that for-loop?

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is that you're thinking of a for-loop as it it were in C.

```
for (int i = 0; i < len(my_tuple); ++I) {
    element = my_tuple[i]
    ...
}
```

In this code, changing the value of `my_tuple` while the loop is running can cause all sorts of problems.

That's not how Python does iteration at all.  Instead it does:

```
iterator = iter(my_tuple)
while True:
    try:
         element = next(iterator)
    except StopIteration:
         break
    ...
```

The `iterator` contains all information needed to iterate through the tuple. That includes both the original value that `my_tuple` had when the iterator was created, plus our current index into the tuple.  Hence changing the value of `my_tuple` doesn't affect the iterator.